# Radio button checked MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on asp.net MVC 3 application. I have created a Razor view and added a radiobutton like this:

```
@Html.RadioButton("radiobutton1", false, new { @class = "answer", id = "_Q_" }) Male
```

In Post action method, I want to see if user selected/checked this radio button, How can I check this ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value from the forms collection:

```
   public ActionResult SubmitFormWithFormCollection(FormCollection formCollection)
   {
       var value = formCollection["_Q_"];

       //Do more stuff
   }
```

Comment: It is always returning false even I check the checkbox

Comment: Have you tried formCollection["\_Q\_"]? As you're overriding the id attribute.  I'd look at using the Html.RadioButtonFor() method instead and put the IsChecked value as a public property in your model.